# Add email attachments from string array

Tags: c#, arrays, email, attachment

I have some code that I am using to send an email with an attachment. The next thing I wanted to do was add attachments from a string array or a List. I had a google but I could only find attachments from byte arrays. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Attachment[] attachments = new Attachment(string array);
mail.Attachments.Add(attachments);
```

I know that won't compile but just so you get the idea. Or is the only way to foreach an array and create attachments one at a time? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `AddRange` on an `AttachmentCollection` so you're out of luck doing it as a slick one-liner (short of creating an extension method).  You could use something like this:

```
string[] attachmentNames = ...

foreach(var attachment in attachmentNames.Select(n => new Attachment(n)))
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```